# scrolling using UIScrollview in a particaular path?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, core-animation

I need to implement scrolling like http://joelb.me/scrollpath/ Is it possible to customize UIScrollView like in the link or any other way to implement?
Edit : That is instead of moving scrollview linearly while scrolling, I want the scrollview to move along a particular path(like Bazier curve) while scrolling

Thanks,
Chandan

Comment: Can you describe what you are after in the question, instead of just posting a link?

Comment: I have updated my question in the edit section...

Comment: if you makea project with phonegap then it is possible and also if you code a layer transition  animation in xcode its easy to make but you must have to put the Aquarius .

Comment: I didn't understand why i got down-vote for this question...

Comment: Instead of downvoting without any reason... Please add comment so i will modify the question in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done customized scrolling in scrollViewDidScroll, that is instead of changing y linearly i have changed y like bazier path using equation.

http://chandanshetty01.blogspot.in/2012/07/uiscrollview-scrolling-in-non-linear.html

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the CAKeyframeAnimation and animating the scrollview offset (on a large scrollview canvas) for particular key paths at fixed key times.

You might want to dig in the CAKeyframeAnimation Class Reference.

Here's a small tutorial on how custom key paths can be achieved in an animation .
http://bit.ly/L05Xsg
You could do it the similar way by animating the contentOffset property of a large UIScrollView.